# SQL not recognizing equal values

Tags: sql, sql-server

**UPDATE:**
I figured out a large part of what caused my problem.  When I queried the database to find the data type, it correctly returned CHAR(4) for t2.sale_code.

However, the GUI did not display leading zero's.  t3.sale_code did not have leading zeros in the file that populated the table.  That's what caused my confusion and I corrected the zero problem.  Now it joins without any CAST or other manipulation.

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_____I have a query:

```
SELECT
  t1.id, t2.sale_code, t3.sale_code, t3.title
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t2.id
```

There are some different one-to-many relationships that I can't control that induce duplication.  I need to do this:

```
WHERE
  t2.sale_code = t3.sale_code
```

However, this just won't work.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I can manually make it work:

```
SELECT
  t1.id, t2.sale_code, t3.sale_code, t3.title
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
  AND t2.dt > t1.dt_active
  AND t2.dt < t1.dt_inactive
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t2.id
WHERE
  t2.sale_code = 4
  AND t3.sale_code = 4
```

For example, this returns a proper matched pair of `sale_code`'s.  However, when I compare them directly (`WHERE t2.sale_code = t3.sale_code) it returns no results.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What is the data type of sale_code in each table?

Comment: Does `sale_code` have the same datatype in both tables?

Comment: That was my first thought too, they both *should* be VARCHAR(4).  I'm going to check one more time just to make sure though.  If they are different types will they still respond to the `>` logic the same way and just not join?

Comment: I was mistaken, it says they are both `CHAR(4)` in the schema provided by the warehouse.  So weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are both character/string types, then you should be quoting them like

```
sale_code = '4'
```

There is likely some bit of data in the column that is not visible, but is getting truncated by the auto cast of int to varchar(4).

You can either use DATALENGTH() to determine if the column has hidden chars, or copy the value into a decent text editor and look at the value in hex view.

A dirty way to get the join to work is to wrap the sale_code with trims, but you are better off cleaning your data.

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(t2.sale_code)) = RTRIM(LTRIM(t3.sale_code))
```

Comment: I can't manipulate the data, it's all stored in a warehouse.  The dirty solution doesn't work either, it's so weird.

Comment: Were you able to see if the data in the column was of the expected length or not?

Comment: Well, I casted them both as VARCHAR(4) and it works.  I guess I'm stuck with something like that.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm concerned about the performance but I don't think there's much else I can do other than work with what I'm given.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add to your inner join

```
SELECT
  t1.id, t2.sale_code, t3.sale_code, t3.title
FROM
  t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t2.id AND t2.sale_code = t3.sale_code
```

Comment: That is logically equivalent of having it in the where clause.